# How to subscribe to inner Flux/Mono automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a Flux of (bounded) Flux that I want to transform into a Flux of Long, where the Long is the size of the inner Flux:

```
   Flux.just( Flux.just(1, 2, 3),  Flux.just(1, 2)  )
       .map(Flux::count)
       .log()
       .subscribe();
```

The execution log is the following:

```
onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] FluxArray.ArraySubscription)
request(unbounded)
onNext({ "operator" : "Count" })
onNext({ "operator" : "Count" })
onComplete()
```

Flux::count returns a Mono, not a Long. Is there any operators to unpack this inner mono automatically when subscribing to the main flux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap()` is there for you:

> Transform the elements emitted by this `Flux` asynchronously into `Publisher`s, then flatten these inner publishers into a single `Flux` through merging, which allow them to interleave.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! the problem I try to solve is actually slightly different : what operator should I use if the inner mono is not directly in the parent flux : `Flux<Tuple<String, Mono<Long>>>` to `Flux<Tuple<String, Long>>` Can we still use flatmap in this case?

Comment: Hm. No, I think this one isn't going to work. That is rally nested value of the `Tuple` and I somehow not sure that there is something to process its part on demand.

Comment: Finally found a solution without subscribing the inner flux/mono. After groupBy I chain the following operator and I create the tuple after counting the elements of the group:  `.flatMap( group -> group.count().map( count -> Tuples.of( group.key(), count )));`

Comment: Great! Code into the studio please!